# Card application with enums returning null

Tags: java, enums

As the title says, i'm experimenting with Enums yet i'm getting completely the wrong output. Instead of getting the card suit and rank i'm getting two null values.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

**Card class**

```
public class Card {



    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;



    public Card (Suit suit, Rank rank) {

    }

    public Suit getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

      public void setSuit(Suit suit)
    {
    this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getRankValue()
    {
    return rank;
    }

    public void setRankValue(Rank rank)
    {
    this.rank = rank;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString ( ) { return ( rank + " of " + suit ); }

    }
```

**Hand class**

```
public class Hand {

private Card theCards[ ];
private int numCards;
private static final int max = 5;

public Hand ( )
{
 theCards = new Card [max];
 numCards = 0;
}
public void addCard( Card aCard ) 
{ 
     if (numCards < max) theCards[numCards++] = aCard; 
}
@Override
public String toString ( ) 
{
   String s = ""; 
   for (int i = 0; i < numCards; ++i)  { 
    s += "\n" + theCards[i]; 
   }
   return s;
}
}
```

**Rank class**

```
public enum Rank {

ACE(1),
TWO(2),
THREE(3),
FOUR(4),
FIVE(5),
SIX(6),
SEVEN(7),
EIGHT(8),
NINE(9),
TEN(10),
JACK(10),
QUEEN(10),
KING(10);

private int rank;

private Rank (int value)

{
 this.rank = value;
}

public int getRankValue() {

return rank;
}
}
```

**Suit class**

```
public enum Suit {

HEARTS , SPADES , CLUBS , DIAMONDS 
}
```

**And my class for creating a card and calling the toString.**

```
public class HandDriver {

public static void main( String[] args ){ 

Card c1 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("HEARTS"),Rank.valueOf("TEN"));
System.out.print (c1.toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Card (Suit suit, Rank rank) {

}
```

The problem isn't the enum but in your constructor you are literally doing nothing. You get `Suit` and `Rank` as parameter but you don't save them in a local variable. Like in the code below  you need to assign the value of the local instance variable with the parameters that you get through the constructor.

```
public Card (Suit suit, Rank rank) {
   this suit = suit;
   this.rank = rank;
}
```